# How can I trigger one UIViewController of the UITabBarController from another UIViewController?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a project that is a "tab-bar controller" app.  The first button is essentially a Home screen.  The second one displays a UITableView of content.  The third button displays a different UITableView, etc.

From the first view (Home), I have a button on the page that is functionally equivalent to the second-button of the tab controller.  It is an alternative path to get to that UITableView.  I do not want to send a button press to the AppDelegate's UITabBarController.

The code in HomeViewController that I want is essentially this:

```
-(IBAction) touchInsideButton:(id)sender {
    [self presentModalViewController: [appDelegate secondViewController] animated:YES];
}
```

or

```
-(IBAction) touchInsideButton:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate launchSecondViewController: self];
}
```

where, "launchSecondViewController" is (uncomment-out one of the two lines)

```
-(void) launchSecondViewController: (id) sender {
//    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController: secondViewController animated:YES];
//    [self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController: secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Regardless, all three approaches give the same error:

2013-05-16 12:04:26.977 MyApp[55273:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this instance of the second view controller, which you refer to as `secondViewController`, is already in the interface, as a child of the tab view controller. You cannot have it be there and *also* present or push it.

The way to [manipulate a tab bar controller in code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is to set is `selectedViewController` (or selected index). Try doing that instead.

Comment: That was way too easy!  I was over thinking the problem and that should have been obvious.  I did start trying to forward my "touch" event to that button -- again KISS is better.

Comment: It's probably just a question of calm down, take a deep breath, and read the docs!

Comment: Please accept my sincere apologies.  I thought it provided closure and completeness without another answer.  I have used your answers in the past and respect your reputation, expertise and help.

Comment: No apology necessary! It's a genuine problem on Stack Overflow - how to show the outcome. You can edit your own question, making clear that it's an edit; you can submit your own answer; perhaps best of all is to add a comment after my answer, but unfortunately it is hard to present code in a comment.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit on this topic. I think the suggestion there would be, go ahead and post your own answer to you own question. You can do that while still accepting my answer if it gave you the clue you needed, and who knows, someone might upvote *your* answer in future!